# Not setting focus to text field in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom-events

I faced a very interesting issue.
I'm trying to set the **focus** on a input field using Javascript (no jQuery, I tried that also but not worked) using `window.onLoad`.

Just take a look at this fiddle : [setFocusOnLoad](http://jsfiddle.net/ravi441988/r5Rgr/4/)

It's working fine in chrome browser but not in Firefox. Is there any issue in Firefox? How can I resolve it.

**Edited:**
Here is the code I copied in html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onloadFocus(){
                var name = document.getElementById('name');
                //        name.value='window.onload called';
                name.focus();


            }

            window.onload=onloadFocus();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><input type='text' value='' id='name' name='name'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jsfiddle sets the focus later on the javascript-frame, try the standalone-page and it works well: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravi441988/r5Rgr/4/show/

Comment: @Dr. Molle > It's not working on page :(

Comment: @ravi he have given example and its working see it i have also used this many of places

Comment: @Gyan Chandra Srivastava> I tried also looked link it's working fine when I copied fiddel in html page it is not working.

Comment: We cannot solve the issue when we don't know what happens on your page. My guess is that window.onload is overwritten somewhere, use addEventListener( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener )  instead.

Comment: @Dr.Molle> Sir I just copied the fiddle in a html file. I'm editing the question to add html file.

Comment: @Gyan Chandra Srivastava >  i edited question. added html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a slight delay:

```
function onloadFocus(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('name').focus()
    }, 10);
}
```

[Update jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Rgr/9/)

Comment: if i click on run in fiddle issue remains same

Comment: >I added it to my original html file and it worked thanks. Can I know why firefox not setting up focus. Is it a bug??

Comment: @Ravi I'm not sure really, it could be that you have extensions installed that are causing a delay in the loading of the DOM and so passing over any custom scripting. Try getting Firebug and checking for script errors.

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap the function-call into a function, otherwise it will be called immediately, not onLoad(the input is still unknown at this time):

```
window.onload=function(){onloadFocus();}
```

Comment: @ Dr.Molle > It worked fine in Sample Html but not in my project page. Terric's trick worked there... can you tell me what is the actulal proble. I google many developers facing same issue.

Comment: How can I tell you why **it** doesn't work when I don't know **it** (your project-page)?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `window.onload=onloadFocus;` instead of `window.onload=onloadFocus();` because in case of `window.onload=onloadFocus();` onloadFocus will run immediately and at that time input field may not be available.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUYrJ/)

Comment: when i open fiddle it is showing focus on field but when click on run again same problem :(

Comment: @Ravi you should not believe on jsfiddle result in this case. because jsfiddle may contain own code for  focus. I test your code with my changes by creating a simple html page and it workng fine.

Comment: > But it is working fine in chrome? I want to figure out what is issue with firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for it. If you want to focus in Firefox. Write the focus function at the starting of the script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('name').focus();
    // rest of the code here.
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.