# field focus not working in firefox, setTimeout(function(){id.focus();},0);

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, focus

As my application runs on Firefox, and i have got problem to focus on field in Firefox i read many [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542897/not-setting-focus-to-text-field-in-firefox)
here(stack overflow) in all answers i saw below code to fix this problem:

```
function onloadFocus(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('name').focus()
    },0);
}
```

but when you run below code which i have to implement in my application, **NOTE:** this is not pure code , its a demo.
Please read comments written inside the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script >
function abc(id,spanId){
var testVar = document.getElementById(id);
var spanVar = document.getElementById(spanId);

if(id.value =='') {
spanId.innerHTML = 'value is required';
//setTimeout(function(){id.focus();},0); //first close this line of code and execute it.
id.focus(); // then close this line and open comment of above line run it
return false;
}

}
</script>
</head>

<form>
<lable>Enter 1st value</lable><input type="text" onblur="abc(this,test_s1)"/>
<span id="test_s1"></span>
<lable>Enter 2nd value</lable><input type="text" onblur="abc(this,test_s2)"/>
<span id="test_s2"></span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when you execute code with `id.focus();` its working fine(some time in firefox, but working well in all other browsers e.g: chrome), but when you run code with `setTimeout(function(){id.focus();},0);` you will see a infinite loop of focus will start on both text fields. How can i fix this situation??
please check above code in both browsers FIREFOX and CHROME.
If you are not understanding my question please let me know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the setTimeout, you are causing a loop, whereby the next browser focuses the second input before the setTimeout function runs on the first. This causes another unfocus event as the first input is focused by the setTimeout, which triggers another unfocus, which triggers another unfocus .....

You can see that the setTimeout actually does its job fine, by clicking on the page body, rather than on the next input.

You could get round this problem by storing a flag in a global variable stating whether an unfocus event has happened recently, and checking it before applying focus to an input within a setTimeout.

```
<script>
var unfocusJustHappened = false;

function abc(id,spanId){
    var testVar = document.getElementById(id);
    var spanVar = document.getElementById(spanId);

    if(id.value =='') {
        spanId.innerHTML = 'value is required';

        // Update flag
        unfocusJustHappened = true;

        setTimeout(function(){

            // If the flag is true
            if (unfocusJustHappened) {
                id.focus();
            }
        },0);

        setTimeout(function(){

            // After a short period reset the flag to false
            unfocusJustHappened = false;
        },30)

        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```